Is the Ball-Multiplier for the Fourier Transform auto-adjoint?
Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we define the ball multiplier as the operator
$$Sf(x) := \int_{|\xi|<1} \hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i x\cdot\xi}d\xi $$
where
$$\hat{f}(\xi) := \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)e^{-2\pi i y\cdot \xi} dy$$
is the Fourier transform of $f$.
Is it true that given $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$
$$\langle Sf,g \rangle =\langle f,Sg \rangle $$
for the standard inner product in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ given by
$$\langle f,g \rangle:= \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)g(x)dx$$
i.e, is the operator $S$ autoadjoint?

Hi and welcome to MSE! I would recommend using \langle \rangle for inner products rather than $<$ and $>$, it'll look better and be better formatted. Have a nice day!

Hey, thank you for the suggestion!

This is a simple corollary of Plancharel's theorem:
$$\langle Sf,g\rangle=\langle \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\chi_{[-1,1]}\hat f),g\rangle=
\langle \chi_{[-1,1]}\hat f,\hat g\rangle=\langle \hat f,\chi_{[-1,1]}\hat g\rangle=\langle f,\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\chi_{[-1,1]}\hat g)\rangle.$$
This is true, more generally, for any real valued multiplier.
